# How do I show $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=0$ then $f(x)=0$ where $f$ is continuous real-valued function?

Tags: integration

This seems very obvious, but feel so stupid that I cannot prove this. How can I do?

I was thinking of using the mean value theorem for integration or uniqueness of such $f$ but they cannot work. I was thinking of using the definition of integration but I'm not sure how I can argue with that.

Comment: Assume $f(c)\neq 0$ for some $c\in [0,1]$. WLOG assume $f(c)>0$. Find a compact set $I$ containing $c$ with non$-$zero length such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$. Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $f(c)\neq 0$ $c\in[0,1]$. Then $f^2(c)>0$. By definition of continuity there exists $\delta\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f^2(x)>0$ for all $x\in B(c,\delta)\cap[0,1]$. From here you can conclude using that $f^2\geq 0$ and properties of integral.